# passing multiple paths to cmdenv in hadoop streaming

Tags: hadoop-streaming

I am using `Hadoop streaming jar` and trying to pass environmental variable which points to multiple paths using `-cmdenv.`

```
hadoop jar ../hadoop-streaming.jar \
-libjars .../something.jar \
-inputFormat ..CustomInputFormat \
-file mapper.py \
-file stream.py \
-cacheFile ../files#aliasname \
-cmdenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/files/1/xyz:/home/files/2/:/home/files/1/abc/ \
-mapper mapper.py \
-input hdfs:/inputfiles/ \
-output hdfs:/outputfiles/ \
-reducer NONE \
-verbose
```

There are couple of queries I have.
1. The environmental variable defined in `cmdenv` is not visible to mapper script
2. Can I provide `hdfs` directories as path to environmental variable?

When I run the execute the `hadoop` command, I getting error in applications logs where it throws "error while loading shared libraries: xyz.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".

Also, I could notice the environmental variable in the stream job
STREAM: `stream.addenvironment=HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER= LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path1>/:<path2>/..`

Please suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: can you paste actual error and which shared object it is rather than abc.so? Also remove space in between "=" of parameter key and value

Comment: Hi, Below is the actual error. LogType: stderr
LogLength: 495
Log Contents:
./imcf.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libMeasureCommon.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./stream.py", line 8, in <module>
    print val
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Comment: So you are missing libraries. check if you need installation of some libs. Do ldd on imcf.exe (I hope its not windows exe and just an extension on Linux)

Comment: The imcf.exe is a C executable. I am passing the required dependency files through -file command to hadoop streaming job and then exporting the environmental variable in cmdenv. This C executable which is copied to all the data nodes where data is present is not able to find the environmental variable and hence the error occurs. ldd on imcf.exe works in the local Linux box when I export the environmental variable manually.

Comment: can you paste the output of ldd and you need to export all those env vars before starting your streaming job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I was able to resolve the issue by adding the C code and dependency libraries to hdfs and then add them to CacheFile with symlinks and providing the symlinks in the environmental variable in cmdenv. See below.

hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar \
 -libjars /<path>/jars/Hadoop_Streaming.jar \
 -inputformat com.hadoop.IMCFInputFormat \
 -outputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat \
 -file mapper.sh \
 -file stream.py \
 -cacheFile hdfs:/<hdfspath>/IMCF/Common/#IMCF_Common \
 -cacheFile hdfs:/<hdfspath>/IMCF/STMC/Common/#IMCF_STMC_Common \
 -cacheFile hdfs:/<hdfspath>/IMCF/STMC/StarLabResults/#IMCF_STMC_StarLabResults \
 -cacheFile hdfs:/<hdfspath>/IMCF/STMC/StarMeasureMembership/#IMCF_STMC_StarMeasureMembership \
 -cacheFile hdfs:/<hdfspath>/IMCF/STMC/StarMedicalCase/#IMCF_STMC_StarMedicalCase \
 -cacheFile hdfs:/<hdfspath>/IMCF/STMC/StarMedicalClaim/#IMCF_STMC_StarMedicalClaim \
 -cacheFile hdfs:/<hdfspath>/IMCF/STMC/StarPrcdrTracking/#IMCF_STMC_StarPrcdrTracking \
 -cacheFile hdfs:/<hdfspath>/IMCF/STMC/StarRxClaim/#IMCF_STMC_StarRxClaim \
 -cacheFile hdfs:/<hdfspath>/IMCF/STMC/Stars/#IMCF_STMC_Stars \
 -cacheFile hdfs:/<hdfspath>/IMCF/STMC/StarDerived/#IMCF_STMC_StarDerived \
 -cacheFile hdfs:/<hdfspath>/lkup_files/MFW_meas_comp_def.lkup#MFW_meas_comp_def.lkup \
 -cacheFile hdfs:/<hdfspath>/lkup_files/MFW_msr_cdset_x_cdset_lst.lkup#MFW_msr_cdset_x_cdset_lst.lkup \
 -cacheFile hdfs:/<hdfspath>/lkup_files/MFW_msr_criteria.lkup#MFW_msr_criteria.lkup \
 -cacheFile hdfs:/<hdfspath>/lkup_files/MFW_run_params.properties#MFW_run_params_HMO.env \
 -cacheFile hdfs:/<hdfspath>/IMCF/MainModule/imcf.exe#imcf.exe \
 -mapper mapper.sh \
 -input /<hdfspath>/Stars_Ext_Tbl/IMCF_CIF_EXT/ \
 -output /<hdfspath>/stream_output/ \
 -reducer NONE \
 -cmdenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH=IMCF_Common:IMCF_STMC_Common:IMCF_STMC_StarLabResults:IMCF_STMC_StarMeasureMembership:IMCF_STMC_StarMedicalCase:IMCF_STMC_StarMedicalClaim:IMCF_STMC_StarPrcdrTracking:IMCF_STMC_StarRxClaim:IMCF_STMC_Stars:IMCF_STMC_StarDerived \
 -verbose
```